# Conversion of arbitrary based numbers to different arbitrary base without division.

Tags: education, perfect-powers

I'm attempting to find a better way of converting arbitrary based numbers.

I've been taught to first convert the number, lets say `235 (base7)`to its equivalent in decimal or base 10.

```
 2       3       5

 2*7^2 + 3*7^1 + 5*7^0

 98    + 21    + 5

 = 124 (dec)
```

Then through the process of long division, convert it to a different base equivalent number.

```
124(dec) -> x(base 3)

 124 / 3 =  41 + 1/3

 41 / 3  =  13 + 2/3

 13 / 3  =   4 + 1/3

 4 / 3   =   1 + 1/3

 1 / 3   =   0 + 1/3
```

Then by reading the remainders from the bottom up the result in base3 is

```
 1 1 1 2 1
```

Its doable, but this method requires a bit of time to preform, and it can become difficult when the numbers become large.

For number bases of the power of 2, `2 4 8 16...` the conversion between these numbers is easy to preform with number grouping.

To convert  `711 (oct)` to `(base 4)` its possible to do so by converting to bin, then to the base. using a group size of 2, 2^2 = 4

```
      7    1    1

    111  001  001


 | 1|11 |00|1 0|01|

  1  11  00  01  01

  1  3   0   1   1

    1 3 0 1 1 (base 4) = 711 (oct)
```

Or to convert 711(oct) to hex its the same process but with a group size of 4. using a group size of 4, 2^4 = 16

```
      7    1    1

    111  001  001


 | 1|11  00|1 001|

   1  1100  1101

  1  12  5  = 1C9 (hex) = 711(oct)
```

This process is easier, faster, and more reliable.

I want to know if there is a similar process for converting arbitrary bases.

Comment: It's easy to convert between bases $a$ and $a^k$, so base $16$ to base $2$ then to base $8$ is easy. For other conversions .... good luck!